# CAST Empty Alias to Integer From Union Of 2 SQL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a SQL that running normally in MySQL. But since I was asked to change the database to PostgreSQL, the SQL cannot run normally. It's because datatype. Let's look the example:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM tbl_first
  UNION ALL
SELECT D, ' ', F FROM tbl_second
```

Let's say column B have a datatype as `Integer`. When I run on PostgreSQL, the notice say `"invalid input syntax for integer: LINE 3: ' ',"`. Maybe my guess is right, this is due to the definition of `' '` column.

I always use `CAST(COLUMN AS INTEGER)` method to cast a column which string or character datatype to Integer. But in my case it always give me an error.

How best way to solve this? Thank's.

Comment: Why not use `select d, null::integer, f from tbl_second` instead?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the answer, your method is works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast column `B` to text:

```
SELECT A, B::text, C FROM tbl_first
UNION ALL
SELECT D, ' ', F FROM tbl_second
```

In a union query, all columns in the same position usually need to have the same type.

Comment: Yes, union need all colums in the same type, I'm new about postgresql, and don't know how to cast. Thank's for the answer. It's work!